# SQL logic context/scenario

Tags: java, sql, spring-jdbc

I have this scenario: user want to see tons of information about himself. For example: age, name, status, income, job, hobby, children's name, wife's name, chief's name, grandfather/grandmother names. About 50 variables. And he can choose any of variables to show the information.
So, I have this class `*Impl.java` passing with 50 params. Within 50 params, let's say 25 will be null and others will be shown. And it will return the selected information.
How can I create a query in SQL to get the columns selected from params? Should I create a procedure and then do the query `select`? Or is it bad to do what I'm trying to achieve?
I'm using `Web Services` and `Spring JDBC`. If requires more information, I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Building a SELECT statement to return arbitrarily selected columns can be tricky (dynamic SQL) at best and dangerous (SQL Injection) at worst. If there are only 50 columns and the query used to pull them is relatively trivial*, I'd say write the query to pull all possible values for one user and then have the application sift and sort through the data they actually want to see.

*It really does seem like the query should be trivial. At a super-high average of 25 bytes per column that'd be 1250 bytes, aka nothing in 21st century terms, and at maybe one row per table joined via primary key it should still be sub-100th-second work.